# Python: Setting conditions within if-elif-else block

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following code snippet:

```
for row in lst:
    if 'Type' in row[0]:
        for col in range(len(row)):
            #do something
    elif (not 'Type' or '') in row[0]:
        for col in range(len(row)):
            #do something
row_count +=1
```

For the second part of `elif (not 'Type' or '')` how do I NOT increase the `row_count` counter if its true for `row[0]` = `''` only but increase when `row[0]` != `Type` is met ? I coudnt set the counter condition withion the if-else block as im scanning row by row in `lst` which is basically a row read from a csv reader in python.

Perhaps I'm complicating myself too much?
Advices plz.

[EDIT] - Here's the actual code, im using xlwt module to write into worksheets.

```
for row in spamReader:
    if 'Type' in row[0]:
        for col in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(0,col,convert(row[col]),style) 
    elif (not 'Type' or '') in row[0]:
        for col in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_count,col,convert(row[col]),style)
    row_count +=1
```

More details:
I have this csv file where Im scanning row by row. Whichever row where its 1st value is 'Type', im writing it in another xls worksheet so that it becomes top row. Else, it just continues to copy row by row. But, when the row's 1st column is empty, i.e. '', it suppose to pass/neglect it.

Comment: Can you move the `row_count` statement into the if block?

Comment: When would you like to increase `row_count`?

Comment: if i move the `row_count` statement into the block, at which indent am I suppose to aligned it? coz, once it increments the counter, the next block would be utilizing it in the `do something` statement.

Comment: @wong2: after each `row` being processed in the `lst`

Comment: @siva: What?  Are you asking how to set a "flag" inside the `else` so that you can add another `if` around the increment of the row_count?  Is that what you're asking?  You really need to clarify what you're trying to do.  Try writing a much, much longer, much, much more detailed explanation of what is supposed to happen.  Details help.

Comment: Uhh.. What `(not 'Type' or '') in row[0]` is supposed to mean? Unless I overlooked some new feature of Python 3.0, `(not 'Type' or '')` just evaluates to `''`. Doesn't it?

Comment: @atzz: erm.. not sure, but when i tested it, its writing all the `not 'Type'` rows. the question is how do i skip empty strings but with `not 'Type'` condition met? sorry for the less details earlier.

Comment: Rows containing 'Type' won't reach the `elif` because they are consumed by the preceding `if`. And if `row[0]` is a string, then `'' in row[0]` is always true, so your `elif` condition is a tautology and `elif` is equivalent to plain `else`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for row in spamReader:
    if row[0] == '':
        continue

    if 'Type' in row[0]:
        row_count = 0
        ... start new worksheet ...

    for col in range(len(row)):
        ws.write(row_count,col,convert(row[col]),style)
```